# How to update entire dataset without breaking existing enter/exit bindings?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**EDIT**

I've created a simpler example derived almost exclusively from Mike Bostock's [Sankey](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/) diagram example. You can see a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/0v5c4sgw/) that demonstrates the same thing. This simply loads a Sankey visualization and then re-loads the exact same data at a regular interval.

This uses the general update pattern I believe and as this only deals with nodes/edges that have `entered` I would expect nothing to happen. In reality SVG keeps getting layered on top over and over. You can see the update code is very simple - go reload the original data source and this should mean that there are no new entered data entries:

```
// Initial Load
d3.json("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41796243/JSFiddle/D3%20Update/energy.json", function(energy) {
     update(energy);
});

// Refresh
setInterval(function() {
    d3.json("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41796243/JSFiddle/D3%20Update/energy.json", function(energy) {
       update(energy);
    })
}, 2000);
```

Within the update function the edges should simply get rendered for any new data entries:

```
 var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link")
      .data(data.links)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", path)
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.max(1, d.dy); })
      .sort(function(a, b) { return b.dy - a.dy; });
```

When this renders however you can see from the screenshot below how this incorrectly keeps updating the edges:

### [image]

---

**Original**

I've helped produce a visualization which I'm trying to run an update for. A lot of the examples I've seen just do an in memory update of the object data - whereas I want to go back to the server and request a replacement data-set to see if new items have been introduced/values changed. This visualization looks like this:

[image]

I initially load the data using the `d3.json` call like:

```
d3.json("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41796243/JSFiddle/Sankey/data.json", 
        function(data) {
            sankey.data(data);
            sankey.render();
        }
);
```

What I then want to do is load a new JSON file (that contains almost identical data - with a few minor changes) and update the visualization:

```
$("#update").click(function() {
    d3.json("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41796243/JSFiddle/Sankey/data2.json",
    function(data) {
        sankey.data(data);
        sankey.render();
    })
})
```

What happens however is that the data seems to lose all of its bindings. If I keep clicking update button then you can see the semi opaque lines keep getting added on top of each other producing a picture like this:

[image]

Now while I'm not explicitly removing the links, just adding new ones with the following code, I didn't expect to be adding any links when the graph itself hasn't changed:

```
// Create new links between nodes
    var links = vis.append("g")
                    .selectAll(".link")
                    .data(data.links);

    links.enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", sankey.link())
        .style("stroke-width", "6px")
        .style("marker-end", "url(#end-arrow)")
        .style("stroke", "#fff")
        .style("opacity", 0.2)
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("hover-opacity", 0.5)
        .sort(function (a, b) { return b.dy - a.dy; });
```

What I'd expect is for the lines to remain as they are, and that there would be no new links, instead just updates to the existing ones. As I'm not explicitly updating the existing links, I wouldn't expect them to change appearance.

So the question is why is this happening (my guess would be due to a full re-load of the data) and how can I prevent it, while still loading the entire data set again?

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/1do29p2b/) to demonstrate the issue. The interesting code is in the `control.render` function between lines #97-#150.

Comment: Create a closured update pattern. See the Update() function here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234

Comment: @Incodeveritas Isn't that exactly what I'm doing already? `vis.append("g").selectAll(".link").data(data.links);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your implementation is that you constantly add two new `g`elements when calling your `update` function. You can observe that in your JSFiddle (after a while, you have quite a bunch of `g`s in your `svg` element).

How to solve that? Well, there's plenty of approaches, here's an example:

First you add some containers to place your elements in:

```
var linkContainer = svg.append('g');
var nodeContainer = svg.append('g');
```

(you do that right after you define the `svg`, i.e. **outside** the update function.

Next, you add the elements into these containers, in the update function:

```
var link = linkContainer.selectAll(".link")....
```

and likewise for the nodes.

This should fix the issue, I hope.

Another approach would be binding the groups in the `svg` element to some random fixed data and use `.enter().append()` on that (thus making sure it's only added once, for the data is fixed...)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Indeed that does help. Here's a demonstration of your suggestion fully working http://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/0v5c4sgw/4/ . I actually see the obvious mistake too now - the `g` that I'm selecting from has no elements on it - and therefore the data join fails.

Comment: ok cool, I shall keep the answer as it is now then. Good luck with your project and thanks for the quick feedback!